# How to programmatically fire keydown event in ExtJS 4

Tags: event-handling, extjs4.1

In ExtJs 4 how can I programmatically fire 'keydown' (or 'keypress') event (on TAB key) ?
I should want to simulate a TAB key pression in response to another event.
I have tried with code (in this event handler) :

```
field.fireEvent('keydown', {keyCode: 9})
```

but it's not working...

Answer (score 0):

You may have to spy your DOM a bit (to see what elements are there, like `fileInputEl` in the example below), but this works for me:

```
var uploadField = Ext.getCmp( 'uploadField' );        
uploadField.fileInputEl.dom.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for a solution .... I have a numberfield component and a pop-up keyboard... when I try to click on key ('.') on the keyboard-pop-up... I want to attach to numberfield (like when you press '.')... but nothing happens. I try this:

```
        // Ext version 5.1

        var field = Ext.getCmp('numberfield-test');

        var event = Ext.create('Ext.event.Event', {
            key: 110  // Want to emulate '.' key
        });

        // none of the following works
        field.fireEvent('keydown', [ field, event ]);
        field.fireEvent('keypress', [ field, event ]);
        field.fireEvent('keyup', [ field, event ]);

        // neither this ones
        field.fireEvent('keydown', field, event);
        field.fireEvent('keypress', field, event);
        field.fireEvent('keyup', field, event);
```

[image: keyboard-pop-up]

Comment: Ext.create('Ext.event.Event', { keyCode: 110 }) works for me